# fullcalendar cannot jump to date with gotodate function

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

Why I can not jump to january ?

if I click nothing happens:

```
  const handleChange = (e: IYearOption) => {
    if(e.value === '1') {
      console.log('HI');
      ref.current?.getApi().gotoDate('2023-01-01')
    }

        <section>
          <Select
            name="select-year"
            className="select-year"
            placeholder="Select date"
            onChange={handleChange}
            options={optionYear}
            styles={{ menuPortal: base => ({ ...base, zIndex: 9999 }) }}
          />
        </section>


      <FullCalendar
        ref={ref}
        now={new Date().toISOString()}
        initialDate={new Date().toISOString()}
        scrollTime={milliseconds - 86400000}
        resources={resource}
        // @ts-ignore
        events={query}
        schedulerLicenseKey="XXX" 
        plugins={[ resourceTimelinePlugin, interactionPlugin, dayGrid, scrollGrid ]}
        initialView='resourceTimelineYear'
        allDayContent={(el) => console.log(el)}
        views={{
          resourceTimelineYear: {
            slotDuration: { hours: 24 },
          }
        }}
        locale='de'
        selectOverlap
        stickyHeaderDates
        droppable
        height='auto'
        stickyFooterScrollbar
        aspectRatio={0.8}
        editable={false}
        select={handleSelectDate}
        selectable={true}
        selectMirror={true}
        //eventChange={(e) => console.log(e)}
        
        resourceGroupField='building'
      />
```

I tried to set gotoDate in milliseconds but this also not works. I am very thankful if anyone can help me and solve this issue.

€: He only jumps to the todays date not the given date

Comment: What debugging have you one? Is the `goToDate`  function definitely executed? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @ADyson no errors it works but it jumps to todays date not the given date